# How do I stop the random name generator from changing names on refresh?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a random name generator so that when the website page loads a random name comes up. I'm not that experienced at coding so please bear with me.

I've tried using localStorage and sessionStorage.

```
const firstNames = ["Emily","Hannah","Madison","Ashley","Sarah","Alexis","Samantha","Jessica","Elizabeth","Taylor","Lauren","Alyssa","Kayla","Abigail","Brianna","Olivia","Emma","Megan","Grace","Victoria","Rachel","Anna","Sydney","Destiny","Morgan","Jennifer","Jasmine","Haley","Julia","Kaitlyn","Nicole","Amanda","Katherine","Natalie","Hailey","Alexandra"];

const getRandomNumber = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * max);

const getRandomName = () =>
`${firstNames[getRandomNumber(firstNames.length)]}`;

document.getElementById('random-name').innerText = getRandomName();
```

Comment: You want to keep the last-generated name on page reloads, correct? Just clarifying because the question body doesn't have any indication of that, just the title

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the generated name in localStorage or sessionStorage before returning for getRandomName function.
After storing check if you have the name already available in storage if yes use it else generate the save it to storage and then use it.

```js
const firstNames = ["Emily","Hannah","Madison","Ashley","Sarah","Alexis","Samantha","Jessica","Elizabeth","Taylor","Lauren","Alyssa","Kayla","Abigail","Brianna","Olivia","Emma","Megan","Grace","Victoria","Rachel","Anna","Sydney","Destiny","Morgan","Jennifer","Jasmine","Haley","Julia","Kaitlyn","Nicole","Amanda","Katherine","Natalie","Hailey","Alexandra"];

const getRandomNumber = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * max);

const getRandomName = () => {        
window.localStorage.name = window.localStorage.name || firstNames[getRandomNumber(firstNames.length)];
return window.localStorage.name;
}

document.getElementById('random-name').innerText = getRandomName();
```

```html
Name: <span id="random-name"></span>
```

`